How do I add a custom module block to any theme's bottom-most region programmatically?
I have a custom block in my custom module that I want to appear automatically at the bottom-most region of any theme. I want this to happen when the module is installed.
Similar to how the 'Powered by Drupal' block is automatically placed on any default theme's bottom-most region, how can this be done programmatically?
I've been digging through the core system.module, but I can't find any clue on how they did it. I know you can go do a single item export of a block's configuration yml file and just paste a copy into the config/install directory, but then I have to do that each time I change the theme.
I want to know how the 'system_powered_by_block' does it on the fly.
Thanks in advance.

This is the default config of the installed theme, see for example /core/themes/olivero/config/optional/block.block.olivero_powered.yml. Only the theme knows the bottom-most region.
